# How to deal with defaultRolePrefix="ROLE_" in Spring Security update from 3.2.7 to 4.0.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application works on `Spring Security 3.2.7.RELEASE`. 
Now, I'd like to update it to `4.0.2.RELEASE`.

After hours of debug I have found that Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE uses `defaultRolePrefix="ROLE_"`

in

`org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.hasAnyAuthorityName(String prefix, String... roles)` method

In my application I use roles without this prefix and accordingly I get `AccessDeniedException`.

How to configure Spring Boot in order to use `SecurityExpressionRoot.defaultRolePrefix=""` ?

Comment: I'm sorry to see you had difficulty migrating. Did you see that this is covered in the migration guide? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4 Specifically if you follow the link I sent you should get to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have found a reason of that after 2 hours of debug spring security project. I have changed hasRole to hasAuthority and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to see you found the issue. I was hoping that if you (or others) encounter any more issues with the migration that the guide I provided will help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution how to fix it. I need to change hasRole to hasAuthority, for example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERMISSION_CREATE_NODE')")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the other hand you can remove role prefix ass described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828767/635891). In this cas you are free to use other annotations.