# How do I remove the ROLE_ prefix from Spring Security with JavaConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to remove the "ROLE_" prefix in Spring Security. The first thing I tried was:

```
http.servletApi().rolePrefix("");
```

That didn't work, so I tried creating a `BeanPostProcessor` as suggested in http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing-disable. That didn't work either.

Finally, I tried creating my own `SecurityExpressionHandler`:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
          .antMatchers("/restricted").fullyAuthenticated()
          .antMatchers("/foo").hasRole("mycustomrolename")
          .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
  }

  private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
      DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
      defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
      return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
  }
```

However, this doesn't work either. If I use "hasAuthority(roleName)" instead of `hasRole`, it works as expected.

Is it possible to remove the ROLE_ prefix from Spring Security's hasRole check?

Comment: Strange the `BeanPostProcessor` works for me (you did declare it as a `static` bean method and included the `PriorityOrdered` so that it runs very early?) and the same for expression handler. We also have a `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` configured with the prefix set the `null`.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code for the `BeanPostProcessor ` directly from the documentation. I tried putting the `@Bean` in my `@Configuration` class for Spring Security and in my `@SpringBootApplication` class. I added a `System.out.println` to ensure it's being configured before Spring Security too. `hasAuthority` works as expected, so I guess I'll just use that instead.

Comment: We have it in a non spring boot application. Could it be that that is interfering or that the security of boot is somehow still configured earlier?

Answer (score 37):

Starting from Spring 4.2, you can define the prefix with a single bean, as described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4134

```
@Bean
GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
}
```

XML version:

```
<beans:bean id="grantedAuthorityDefaults" class="org.springframework.security.config.core.GrantedAuthorityDefaults">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Didnt Worked for me

Comment: Does not work: see the 4th comment in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756013

Comment: There is a difference between a GrantedAuthority and a Role. This answer is for GrantedAuthority.

Comment: For those who have exception with annotation: move the @Bean instance from the security config to the MVC config Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971937/ugrade-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc2-exception-no-servletcontext-set

Comment: It works with `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String)` but not works with `@Secured(String)`.

Comment: It works with JSR250's `@RolesAllowed` (which is said to be superior over springs' own `@Secured` annoatation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394049/913093)

Answer (score 8):

The following configuration works for me.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.expressionHandler(new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        @Override
        protected SecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi) {
            WebSecurityExpressionRoot root = (WebSecurityExpressionRoot) super.createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication, fi);
            root.setDefaultRolePrefix(""); //remove the prefix ROLE_
            return root;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It appears the new `GrantedAuthorityDefaults` will change the prefix for the `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` and the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, but it doesn't modify the `RoleVoter.rolePrefix` that is setup from `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`.

The RoleVoter.rolePrefix is what is used for `@Secured("ADMIN")` style of method security.

So along with the `GrantedAuthorityDefaults`, I had to also add this `CustomGlobalMethodSecurity` class to override the defaults for `RoleVoter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class CustomGlobalMethodSecurity extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();

        //Remove the ROLE_ prefix from RoleVoter for @Secured and hasRole checks on methods
        accessDecisionManager.getDecisionVoters().stream()
                .filter(RoleVoter.class::isInstance)
                .map(RoleVoter.class::cast)
                .forEach(it -> it.setRolePrefix(""));

        return accessDecisionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, how to get access to AccessDecisionManager?

Comment: @Ninja The AccessDecisionManager will have to be configured in an additional class, as I don't believe it can be done from the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I think you'll just need to create a new Configuration class that extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

Comment: But that only helps if you use `@Secured` annotation because `@Secured` values are evaluated in `RoleVoter` class, and `@PreAuthorize` annotation expression evaluated in `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter` class, publishing another bean `new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("")` with prefix argument in constructor which also affect on `@PreAuthorize`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are prior to 4.2 and are using so called voters (you are if you use annotations like @hasRole etc) then you need to define below beans in the context:

```
@Bean
public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
    return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
}

@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
    return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}
```

These beans are used to create evaluation context for spell expressions and they have a defaultRolePrefix set to 'ROLE_'. Although it depends on your use case. This one worked for me and above didn't.

EDIT: answering question about xml configuration -> of course it can be done in xml. Everything done in java config can be written in xml configuration. Here is example (although I did not test it so there might be a typo or something):

```
<bean id="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="defaultRolePrefix" value=""></property>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="defaultRolePrefix" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent in XML configuration?

Comment: I have updated my answer with xml config... but as I wrote, there might be some kind of a mistake - I did not tested it out. The general rule is - everything in java config can be done in xml as well.

Comment: fails in my JHipster application right during boot, with `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: .......; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
`

Comment: Petr - it's just a wild guess, but if you get this error it probably means you do not have a web context so you do not need the second bean - DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler. Anyway each configuration is different, so it is hard to tell what the problem really is in your case guys. For me these two beans fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Spring Boot 2, you can create this bean to override the **RoteVoter** prefix

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return  new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("<anything you want>");
}
```

---

It works because when **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration** creates **AccessDecisionManager** in the method **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.accessDecisionManager()**. Here is the snippet of code, notice the null check on **grantedAuthorityDefaults**

```
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    ....
    RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults =
            getSingleBeanOrNull(GrantedAuthorityDefaults.class);
    if (grantedAuthorityDefaults != null) {
        roleVoter.setRolePrefix(grantedAuthorityDefaults.getRolePrefix());
    }
    decisionVoters.add(roleVoter);
    decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
    return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot 2.3 I got this exception at boot time:

```
Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: 
Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

Here is my solution:

```
@Configuration
@Import(RolePrefixConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MyWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  public static class RolePrefixConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
      log.debug("remove prefix 'ROLE_' from grantedAuthorityDefaults");
      return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
    }

  }
   
   // ... your usual config 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post summary working solutions for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    /**
     * Allow skip ROLE_ when check permission using @Secured, like:
     *  @Secured({AuthorityConstants.ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN})
     */
    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();
        setAuthorityRolePrefix(accessDecisionManager, "");
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }

    private void setAuthorityRolePrefix(AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager, String rolePrefix) {
        accessDecisionManager.getDecisionVoters().stream()
                .filter(RoleVoter.class::isInstance)
                .map(RoleVoter.class::cast)
                .forEach(it -> it.setRolePrefix(rolePrefix));
    }

    /**
     * Allow skip ROLE_ when check permission using @PreAuthorize, like:
     * @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER', 'SYSTEM_ADMIN')")
     */
    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
public SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthority()                             
{     
    SimpleAuthorityMapper mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();       
    mapper.setPrefix("");      
    return mapper;      
}

@Override   
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  
{  
KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthority());
auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best answer which I ever saw:

```
    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }
```

```
package com.senla.course.hotelapp.security;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter;

public class GrantedAuthorityDefaults implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {

        // remove this if you are not using JSR-250
        if(bean instanceof Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) {
            ((Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }

        if(bean instanceof DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }
        if(bean instanceof DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix(null);
        }
        if(bean instanceof SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter) {
            ((SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter)bean).setRolePrefix("");
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```