# @RolesAllowed vs. @PreAuthorize vs. @Secured

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I want to secure a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@Secured("ADMIN")
public class CompanyController {
}
```

I know that there are different options, but I don't really know which I should use

Comment: The question should be edited to `@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")` and `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416766/spring-security-secured-always-need-role-prefix-how-we-can-remove-the-prefix).)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Security Annotations

All of `@PreAuthorize`, `@RolesAllowed` and `@Secured` are annotations which allow to configure *method security*. They can be applied both on individual methods or on class level, in the latter case the security constraints will be applied to all methods in the class.

Method-level security is accomplished using [Spring AOP proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html).

#### `@PreAuthorize`

**`@PreAuthorize`** annotation allows to specify access constraints to a method using the *Spring Expression Language (SpEL)*. These constraints are evaluated prior to the method being executed and may result in execution of the method being denied if the constraints are not fulfilled. The `@PreAuthorize` annotation is part of the Spring Security framework.

In order to be able to use `@PreAuthorize`, the *`prePostEnabled`* attribute in the
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation needs to be set to `true`:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
```

#### `@RolesAllowed`

**`@RolesAllowed`** annotation has its origin in the [JSR-250](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250) Java security standard. This
annotation is *more limited* than the `@PreAuthorize` annotation because it *only supports role-based security*.

In order to use the `@RolesAllowed` annotation the library containing this annotation needs to be on the classpath, as it is not part of Spring Security. In addition, the *`jsr250Enabled`* attribute of the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation need to be set to `true`:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true)
```

#### `@Secured`

**`@Secured`** annotation is a *legacy Spring Security 2 annotation* that can be used to configure method security. It supports more than only role-based security, but does not support using Spring Expression Language (SpEL) to specify security constraints. It is recommended to use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation in new applications over this annotation.

Support for the `@Secured` annotation needs to be explicitly enabled in the
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation using the *`securedEnabled`* attribute:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
```

#### Which security annotations allow to use SpEL

The following table shows the support for Spring Expression Language in the security annotations that can be used with Spring Security 5:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Security Annotation ║ Has SpEL Support? ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @PreAuthorize      ║        yes        ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @PostAuthorize     ║        yes        ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @PreFilter         ║        yes        ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @PostFilter        ║        yes        ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @Secured           ║        no         ║
╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  @RolesAllowed      ║        no         ║
╚═════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Just a side note here, the \@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity is now deprecated in favor of \@EnableMethodSecurity, which now has the prePostEnabled=true by default, only need to specify the two others: securedEnabled=true or jsr250Enabled=true if needed

Answer (score 20):

`@Secured` and `@RolesAllowed` perform identical functionality in Spring.  The difference is that `@Secured` is a Spring specific annotaiton while `@RolesAllowed` is a Java standard annotation (JSR250).  Neither one of these annotation support SpEL.

`@PreAuthorize` is another Spring specific annotation.  You can perform a lot more powerful operations with `@PreAuthorize` using SpEL.  You can write expressions the limit method invocation based on the roles/permissions, the current authenticated user, and the arguments passed into the method.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or #user.id == authentication.name")
public void deleteUser(User user) {
    ...
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/el-access.html#el-common-built-in

---

As for which to use, it's really up to you.  `@Secure` and `@PreAuthorize` will tie your code to Spring.  If being tied to Spring is not an issue or you need to perform more powerful operations, use `@PreAuthorize`.

Answer (score 5):

All of these are basically the same for your purpose, but `@PreAuthorize` is the best fit for controllers and controller methods. `@Secured` and `@RolesAllowed` are intended for describing service layer security attributes.

Also be aware for `@PreAuthorize` annotation to work you must define a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
...
}
```

Comment: Why is `@PreAuthorize` the best fit for controllers?