# Spring security @Secured always need ROLE_ prefix, how we can remove the prefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am  checking a role "XXXXX" in my controller . But it is working only when I add a prefix `"ROLE_"`.

`@Secured("XXXXX")` is not working but when I add the `ROLE_` prefix, it is working fine (`@Secured("ROLE_XXXXX")`is working fine). How can I override this feature in my Spring Boot version 2 project?

Comment: How do you assign roles? That might be the issue

Comment: That is how it is expected isn't it ? [`@Secured`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html)

Comment: Please read through [What does "ROLE_" mean and why do I need it on my role names?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-faq-role-prefix) and an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167971/4214241) on how to do it. Hope this is what you are looking for .

Answer (score 3):

Option 1. You can use `@RolesAllowed("role_name")` instead of `@Secured`

You would need to enable JSR-250 annotations support by annotating @Configuration class with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true)`

Options 2. You can use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_NAME_WITHOUT_ROLE_PREFIX')")` instead of `@Secured`

You would need to enable PreAuthorize annotations support by annotating @Configuration class with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)`