# How to override defaultRolePrefix when using @Secured or @PreAuthorize in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using @Secured("ADMIN"), my role definition is also ADMIN (not ROLE_ADMIN). When I access the API, I am not getting the expected value, it says access denied.

Below is the code, how I have overridden ROLE_ value

```
@PostMapping("/users")
@Loggable   
@Secured({"Administrator"})
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser( @Valid @RequestBody  User userRequest) {
.....
}
```

Implemented CustomAccessDecisionManager where the role prefix (setRolePrefix("")) was set to empty and the CustomDecisionManager was configured in my security configuration file.

The empty role prefix is working fine, the code is below for that

```
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .accessDecisionManager(customAD()).hasRole("ADMIN")
```

But it's not working when I use @Secured.

My DB contains role as USER1, USER2.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled your method security using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`?

Comment: Yes, we have done that. We have used @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)

Comment: There are lots of places where rolePrefix must be set if you want to change the default value, not just AccessDecisionManager. See [SEC-2984](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2984).Further, I noticed a new class was added, that is supposed to help: `GrantedAuthorityDefaults`, by centralizing the definition of the default rolePrefix.

Comment: (cont') However, it does not work, as I just noticed: in order to inject the default prefix in the factory bean of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` (one of the many classes responsible for handling security annotations), it looks for the grantedAuthorithyDefaults bean; however, while instanciating that bean, it loads post-processors that in turn load advices that in turn load .... that finally load the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` again, with the default prefix set to "ROLE_" (this is the default value before an attempt is done to change it) !!!!!