# Roles in Jhipster 4

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

I'm using **jhipster 4**, I have a doubt, I try to put a new role without a pattern **ROLE_*** and it does not work when i use the java annotation **@Secured**.

```
public final class AuthoritiesConstants {   
  public static final String SUPERVISED = "SUPERVISED";
  ...
```

I  check it over many websites about this issue and i can't find any suggest. And i need to put a role called **SUPERVISED** because my app needs to integrate with other.

```
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.SUPERVISED)
public class GreatResource {
...
```

When the webclient do a request with a role SUPERVISED, the action it is denied

Why this happend?

Comment: What have you tried? This should be only spring security configuration not specific to JHipster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134121/how-do-i-remove-the-role-prefix-from-spring-security-with-javaconfig/44828767#44828767

Comment: Yes, you are rigth but the enviroment is this **jhipster**. I talked about jhipster because maybe it inject some extra configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `@Secured` annotation, by default if the supplied role does not start with `ROLE_` then it will be added.  The filter is checking for `ROLE_SUPERVISED` instead of `SUPERVISED`, which is why it is not working as expected.

With [Expression-Based Access Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html), you can check a user's authorities including those without a `ROLE_` prefix.  Use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation combined with the `hasAuthority` expression:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SUPERVISED')")
```