# Custom PreAuthorize annotation in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to understand Spring Security and I'm wondering about creating my own annotations with authorities I've created. I've got something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('STANDARD')")
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface StandardRole {
}
```

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AdminRole {
}
```

and actually it looks like:

```
@AdminRole
@StandardRole
@GetMapping(path = "user", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@RequestParam String login) {
   ...
}
```

but only first annotation works, second one is ommited. I want to do something like `@AllowRoles()` annotation, for example `@Allow({UserType.ADMIN, UserType.STANDARD})` or `@Allow({UserType.ADMIN})`.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pity to force the door open.

I used jsr250 annotation in my SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 ...
```

`@RolesAllowed` in my controller:

```
@RolesAllowed({UserType.TYPE_1, UserType.TYPE_2})
@GetMapping(path = "user", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
```

Finally, at my CustomDetails implementing `UserDetails`:

```
    private static final String PREFIX = "ROLE_";

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                        PREFIX + user.getUserType()));
    }
```

I forgot about "ROLE_" prefix. Code is much cleaner.

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks for the right suggestion of using the `@RolesAllowed` annotation. Regarding the ROLE_ prefix, one can also decide to strip it from the authorities by overriding ` GrantedAuthorityDefaults` bean desribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964633/913093